# Paramiko ssh with tor sock proxy

Tags: python, ssh, proxy, paramiko, tor

I trying use tor proxy for ssh.

First simple connection without `~/.ssh/config`

```
~$ ssh -p <SERVER_POST> <USER>@<SERVER_HOST>
<USER>@<SERVER_HOST>'s password: 

~$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION
<MY_REAL_HOST> <MY_REAL_PORT> <SERVER_HOST> <SERVER_PORT>
```

Second with next `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
ProxyCommand connect -4 -S 127.0.0.1:9050 $(tor-resolve %h 127.0.0.1:9050) %p
```

and connect:

```
~$ ssh -p <SERVER_POST> <USER>@<SERVER_HOST>
<USER>@<SERVER_HOST>'s password: 

~$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION
<NOT_MY_REAL_HOST> <NOT_MY_REAL_HOST> <SERVER_HOST> <SERVER_PORT>
```

Now with `paramiko`:

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> client = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> proxy = None
>>> client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password,
...                port=port, sock=proxy)
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('echo $SSH_CONNECTION')
>>> print((stdout.read() + stderr.read()).decode('utf8'))
<MY_REAL_HOST> <MY_REAL_PORT> <SERVER_HOST> <SERVER_PORT>
```

All work fine. But when I try set up proxy:

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> client = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(
...     'connect -4 -S 127.0.0.1:9050 $(tor-resolve %h 127.0.0.1:9050) %p')
>>> client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password,
...                port=port, sock=proxy)
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('echo $SSH_CONNECTION')
>>> print((stdout.read() + stderr.read()).decode('utf8'))
```

I have next exception for python 3.4:

```
Exception: Error reading SSH protocol bannersequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1535, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 271, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 424, in _read_timeout
    x = self.__socket.recv(128)
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/proxy.py", line 93, in recv
    result = ''.join(self.buffer)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1412, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1539, in _check_banner
    raise SSHException('Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol bannersequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1535, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 271, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 424, in _read_timeout
    x = self.__socket.recv(128)
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/proxy.py", line 93, in recv
    result = ''.join(self.buffer)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/registrator/main.py", line 70, in <module>
    client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password, port=port, sock=proxy)
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 242, in connect
    t.start_client()
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 346, in start_client
    raise e
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1412, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1539, in _check_banner
    raise SSHException('Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e))
paramiko.s
```

For python 2.7 same exception with other stacktrace:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/registrator/main.py", line 70, in <module>
    client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password, port=port, sock=proxy)
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 242, in connect
    t.start_client()
  File "/home/tbicr/Project/env27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 339, in start_client
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

So connection with ssh client and tor work fine, but with `paramiko` not.

Why it's not work and how I can fix it for python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609443/paramiko-proxycommand-fails-to-setup-socket.

Comment: Does your app use gevent? I recently had the same response and found it was because gevent's socket patching seemed to interfere.

Comment: I do not use it in my code, but `gevent` package can be installed with `virtualenv`.